# Silex Server Cache between sessions

Tags: session, caching, server, persistence, silex

How I can persist data value between requests from all sessions in a API Rest server?

GET requests from Server always return same information. It is not necessary to extract info from database, process, generate the JSON and response. I would like to response this request from a cache between sessions in order to do faster my web page.

So far, I use  $app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider()); and then, when I have the response, put the info in the session with  $eventsCache = $app['session']->get('eventsCache');
It works properly but only in the same session.
I would like to have same information for all sessions. Same behaviour of SessionServiceProvider but for all of them without depending on the session.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds that you need an HTTP cache, fortunately for you [Symfony comes with a PHP implementation of an HTTP reverse cache](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#symfony-reverse-proxy) and [Silex has a provider for it](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/http_cache.html)

Comment: thanks @mTorres As soon as I have some results. I'll tell you. Thanks.

Comment: That would be cool :-)

Comment: I am not sure if it is the Silex component I was looking for. I would like to manage the cache from any request in the controller. I would like to delete it  or modify the value from any request. I have been searching some other frameworks or components, and I found [link] (https://github.com/moust/silex-cache-service-provider) I will try it, @mTorres

Comment: At the end, the best option to solve my problem was use moust/silex-cache-service-provider. Thanks @mTorres for your answer.